# How to make a 3D interpolation function?

Tags: interpolation

I have a following data,

```
 x , y , z, f(x,y,z)
0.0,0.0,0.0,1.532704
0.04,0.0,0.0,1.520342
0.08,0.0,0.0,1.484285
0.12,0.0,0.0,1.426193
0.16,0.0,0.0,1.353395
0.2,0.0,0.0,1.269138
0.24,0.0,0.0,1.17861
0.28,0.0,0.0,1.090471
0.32,0.0,0.0,1.005581
0.36,0.0,0.0,0.933414
0.4,0.0,0.0,0.877248
0.44,0.0,0.0,0.836819
0.48,0.0,0.0,0.816123
0.04,0.04,0.0,1.504544
0.08,0.04,0.0,1.478109
0.12,0.04,0.0,1.43574
0.16,0.04,0.0,1.373018
0.2,0.04,0.0,1.294042
0.24,0.04,0.0,1.204979
0.28,0.04,0.0,1.108072
0.32,0.04,0.0,1.016175
0.4,0.04,0.0,0.857493
0.44,0.04,0.0,0.820139
0.48,0.04,0.0,0.802623
```

I want to make a 3D interpolating function using this data. If I use the simple Interpolation,

```
Interpolation[Transpose[{Transpose[{x, y, z}], f}]];
```

Then the following error occurs,
[image]

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Some of the data rows have four elements and some have five elements. Fix the data.

Comment: @BobHanlon Fixed it

Comment: How are you importing the data? Are they in a csv file?

Comment: @MelaGo Yes. Then assigning x = First Column, y = Second Column, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = Import["data.csv"]
  (* {{0, 0, 0, 1.5327}, {0.04, 0, 0, 1.52034}, ... *)
```

All of the z values are 0, so disregarding this dimension

```
ListPlot3D[data[[All, {1, 2, 4}]]]
```

[image]

```
f = Interpolation[data[[All, {1, 2, 4}]]]
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, .48}, {y, 0, .04}]
```

[image]